# Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer does not load local emulator storage

Tags: macos, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer 1.7.0 on macOS 10.14.4 for local development on an Azure function. After attaching to a local emulator the Queues, Blob Containers and Tables are stuck "Loading...".

Steps to Reproduce

1. Click Add Account.
2. Chose "Attach to local emulator". Click next.
3. Fill in fields then click Next.

   - Display name: local-1
   - Blobs port: 10000
   - Files port: 10003
   - Queues port: 10002
   - Tables port: 10003
4. Click Connect.
5. In the Explorer expand Local & Attached > Storage Accounts > local-1 (Key) > Queues.
6. Queues will say "Loading..." for around 30 minutes.
7. Finally an alert will popup saying:

```
Unable to retrieve child resources.
Details: A network error occurred (NetworkTimeoutError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10002)
```

It is also not possible to add a new Queue while it is stuck loading. Right click Queues > Create Queue, then type a queue name and press return does not show the new queue in the list.

What I see in the app:

[image: azure storage explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `Storage Emulator` on Mac (or Linux), please ensure that [`Azurite`](https://github.com/azure/azurite) is installed.

You can read more about the emulator support in Storage Explorer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=macos#work-with-local-development-storage.

Comment: I've installed Azurite and the Storage Explorer now connects. I wish the official MS guide on using the Storage Explorer was clearer that Azurite is needed for Linux *and* macOS. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i got the same Issue in windows 7, azure storage explorer version 1.10.1,  what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix it is to [install Azurite plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Azurite.azurite) on VSCode and run 'Azurite Start Blob Service' from the command pallet.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with `Azure Storage Explore` on `Ubuntu` 22.04, it wasn't recognizing the running `Azurite` services started from the VSCode `Azurite: Start Queue Service`. For me it was resolved by executing next command from bash

```
azurite-queue --silent
```